# Authorize Google Oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3

I have an application ruby on rails and I'm trying to authorize my app in google, but I always get `uninitialized constant`

I tried to use `Google::Auth::Stores::TokenStore` and `Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow`

I followed theses samples https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby#example-command-line and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby?hl=pt-br#upload_a_video

One use `googleauth` and other `google-api-client`.

In my Gemfile

`gem 'google-api-client', '0.8.2', require: 'google/api_client'
gem 'googleauth'`

In my code

Using first example

```
def authorization
    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file './client_secrets.json'
    scope = ['SCOPE']
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: './tokens.yaml')
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store)
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
    if credentials.nil?
        url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(base_url: OOB_URI )
        puts "Open #{url} in your browser and enter the resulting code:"
        code = gets
        credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
    end
end
```

Using second example

```
def authorization
    file_storage = Google::APIClient::FileStore.new(oauth2)
    if file_storage.authorization.nil?
        client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
        flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
        client_id: client_secrets.client_id,
        client_secret: client_secrets.client_secret,
        scope: [YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE]
        )
        client.authorization = flow.authorize(file_storage)
    else
        client.authorization = file_storage.authorization
    end
end
```

Comment: Whats the full error message? What line does it occur on? Is it the same for both auth flows?

Comment: the error is `uninitialized constant Google::Auth::Stores::TokenStore` and `uninitialized constant Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow`

The error raise when I call theses classes, cause it don't found it, but I installed the gem.

Comment: Did you require these in the file/controller where `authorization` is defined?

Comment: I found the solution. I need to add the gem in Gemfile, but in my service I need to require `'google/api_client/auth/file_storage' and `'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'´

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using the second case. When I added the gem `gem 'google-api-client', '>0.7', require: 'google/api_client'` in Gemfile I thought that all was done, but `Google::APIClient::FileStorage` and `Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow` need to require more files, so in the file you will use theses guys add these lines

```
require 'google/api_client/auth/file_storage'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
```